# Saving user input & location from current location Google maps API

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Below is code initially Google maps API for saving user defined data into DB, but i tweaked it to load form in users location marker. and now the save function doesn't help. please help

Register as a Money lender.

Cell:   
         Business 
name:   

      Collateral:  +
                 Laptops,Phones,TVs.
                 Salary Backed Loan
                 Open for Negotiation
                  
      Amount
available:  +
                 Less than K3000
                 More than K3000

```
<div id="message">You have been registered as a money lender at this location.</div>
<script>

var map;
  var marker;
  var infowindow;
  var messagewindow;


  function initMap() {
    var zambia = {lat: -15.376085, lng: 28.366237};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: zambia,
      zoom: 7
    });
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

       if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude



        };


        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(document.getElementById('form'));
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }


  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'We cant seem to find you my friend.' :
                          'Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }



   function saveData() {
    var name = escape(document.getElementById('name').value);
    var address = escape(document.getElementById('address').value);
     var collateral = document.getElementById('collateral').value;
    var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
    var latlng = getCurrentPosition(pos);

    var url = 'phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=' + name + '&address=' + address + '&collateral=' + collateral + 
              '&type=' + type + '&lat=' + latlng.lat() + '&lng=' + latlng.lng();



    downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {

      if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
        infowindow.close();
        messagewindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });
  }




  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request.responseText, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing () {
  }

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: The problem most likely occur on the server side, so I would suggest looking at the logs there to see why the request is not accepted. My initial guess is that you might need to escape the lat/lng components as they contain a dot.

Comment: Also I do not see the code for `getPosition` and I would strongly suggest that you edit your posted code to not include your Google API key

Comment: it was supposed to be getCurrentPosition. but it is still not working. and thank you for pointing it out not to include my key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your exact issue but I failed. So what I did is to revise your code a bit so I can further investigate.

Upon my investigation, there are some lines of your code that seems will likely won't work.

Like this line: `infoWindow.setContent(document.getElementById('form'));`. I believe this line won't work the way you expect it. What I would rather suggest is, to create a js variable that contains html tag - form elements to be exact and the set this as content of your **[Google Maps Javascript API InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)**.

You can check to code below to see what I am talking about:

```
var template = '<form>';
template += '<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name" /><br/>';
template += '<input id="address" type="text" placeholder="address" /><br/>';
template += '<input id="collateral" type="text" placeholder="collateral" /><br/>';
template += '<input id="type" type="text" placeholder="type" /><br/>';
template += '<button onclick="saveData('+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+');">Add my location</button>';
template += '</form>';
infoWindow.setContent(template);
```

You will also notice that I've attached the **'saveData()'** function as an **onclick event** in **button** that we created.

I've also revised your **saveData()** function. As you can see, it accepts two arguments: **lat** and **lng**. These arguments will replace your **latlng** that contains an undefined **getCurrentPosition()** function. If you are referring to **[HTML5 Geolocation getCurrentPosition](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)** method, I am afraid that is not the correct way to implement it.

Here's what the new saveData() function looks like:

```
function saveData(lat,lng) {     
    var pos = {
        lat : lat,
        lng : lng
    }
    var name = escape(document.getElementById('name').value);
    var address = escape(document.getElementById('address').value);
    var collateral = document.getElementById('collateral').value;
    var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
    var url = 'phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=' + name + '&address=' + address + '&collateral=' + collateral + 
              '&type=' + type + '&lat=' + pos.lat + '&lng=' + pos.lng;
    downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {

      if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
        infowindow.close();
        messagewindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });
    //console.log(url);
}
```

Checking **[From Info Windows to a Database: Saving User-Added Form Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/info-windows-to-db)** would be very helpful in your use case.

Hope my answer could help and happy coding!

Comment: one more thing, the messagewindow.open(map,marker) is not working. to notify the user that the info has been submitted successfully.